# Send data from reactive form in component to another component on another route

Tags: angular

I've been trying to develop an angular version of my android Todo app but I've not really understood how data can be sent from my form (to edit and add a task) to my main component that displays the list. For now, my list only displays one item when I add a task. How can I implement the service to add a task to the list and not replace it? (I think it comes from the return statement in my getTask() function but I don't know how to deal with it)

**Here is my edit form component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { TaskServiceService } from "src/app/task-service.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-edit-task",
  templateUrl: "./edit-task.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./edit-task.component.scss"]
})
export class EditTaskComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  title: string = "";
  place: string = "";
  website: string = "";
  time: string = "";
  category: string = "";
  description: string = "";
  task: any;

  public todos = [];
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private _taskService: TaskServiceService
  ) {}

  addTask(task) {
    this.title = task.title;
    this.time = task.time;
    this.place = task.place;
    this.website = task.website;
    this.category = task.category;
    this.description = task.description;

    this._taskService.setTasks(
      this.title,
      this.time,
      this.place,
      this.website,
      this.category,
      this.description
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      title: "",
      place: "",
      website: "",
      time: "",
      category: "",
      description: ""
    });

    this.todos = this._taskService.getTasks();
  }
}
```

**Here is my Service**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class TaskServiceService {
  taskContent = {
    title: "",
    time: "",
    place: "",
    description: "",
    website: "",
    category: ""
  };
  constructor() {}

  setTasks(
    title: string,
    time: string,
    place: string,
    description: string,
    website: string,
    category: string
  ) {
    this.taskContent.title = title;
    this.taskContent.time = time;
    this.taskContent.place = place;
    this.taskContent.description = description;
    this.taskContent.website = website;
    this.taskContent.category = category;
  }

  getTasks() {
    return [
      {
        title: this.taskContent.title,
        time: this.taskContent.time,
        place: this.taskContent.place,
        description: this.taskContent.description,
        website: this.taskContent.website,
        category: this.taskContent.category
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

**Here is my todo list component that displays the list**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { TaskServiceService } from "src/app/task-service.service";

@Component({
  selector: "todo-list",
  templateUrl: "./todo-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./todo-list.component.scss"]
})
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {
  public todos = [];

  constructor(private _taskService: TaskServiceService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.todos = this._taskService.getTasks();
  }
}
```

*Form HTML*

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="todo-item-edit">
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">
      <div class="col-sm-10 inputEdit">
        <mat-form-field class>
          <input matInput placeholder="Title" formControlName="title">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 inputEdit">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Place" formControlName="place">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 inputEdit">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Website" formControlName="website">
        </mat-form-field>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 inputEdit">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Time" formControlName="time">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 inputEdit">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select formControlName="category" placeholder="Category" panelClass="panelCustom">
            <mat-option style="color: black;" value="work">Work</mat-option>
            <mat-option style="color: black;" value="personal">Personal</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 inputEdit">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Description" formControlName="description">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="validBtn-div text-center">
    <button class="validBtn btn" [routerLink]="['']" type="button" (click)="addTask(myForm.value)"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

*TaskList HTML*

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="todo-item" *ngFor="let todo of todos">
    <div class="title">{{ todo.title }}</div>
    <div class="time">{{ todo.time }}</div>
    <div class="place">{{ todo.place }}</div>
  </div>

  <div class="addBtn-div text-center">
    <button class="addBtn btn" [routerLink]="['edit']"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your edit component is supposed to edit **one** task. So why should it have an array of todos. The service, on the other hand, is supposed to contain **all** the tasks: it should have an array of todos. The list component gets the list of tasks from the service. The edit component adds a task to the service. In a real app, the service would send the new task to the server and read the tasks from the server instead of from memory.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it makes sense